In the original QMA verification of the Local Hamiltonian Problem, could Merlin have cheated if he knew which term Arthur would measure?
This a follow-up to a previous question about the verification procedures for Arthur to make sure the witness $|\eta\rangle$ provided by Merlin really does have energy $\lambda\le a$ (and not $\ge b$).
Recall the first protocol - Arthur chooses a random $k$-local term $H_i$ from among the $r$ such terms, acts locally only on those $k$ qubits, and rotates an ancilla answer qubit based on the decomposition of $H_i$. As an aside in the post I had commented that Arthur should choose a term at random, unknowable to Merlin, as a way to bind Merlin and make sure the witness $|\eta\rangle$ really is compliant.  In @Norbert's great answer, he noted that randomness is really needed for averaging purposes.
But even still, if Merlin happened to predict what term $H_i$ will be used for the rotation, couldn't he prepare a fake witness state $|\eta'\rangle$ such that the subsystem for the $k$ qubits from which $H_i$ is composed will satisfy the local test that Arthur will apply (with the other $n-k$ qubits not being relevant?)  Quoting @Norbert below, could Merlin use $|\eta'\rangle$ to convince Arthur that the ground state energy of $H$ is lower than it actually is?

I had originally envisioned a serial process of Merlin providing a bunch of copies of $|\eta\rangle$ to Arthur, with Arthur performing his rotation of a random term for each such copy received.  At each step Arthur secretly tosses his $r$-sided dice to decide which term to measure. Arthur has to make sure that Merlin didn't load the die.
After the discovery of the Marriott-Watrous trick, I guess, clearly Arthur can reuse a single witness and as such Merlin had better provide a compliant, true witness state. Alternatively perhaps if, instead of classically tossing an $r$-sided die, we have a quantum circuit choose the $r^{th}$ term and run the rotation only for that term then Merlin can't cheat quantum physics and know a-priori what term the quantum circuit will choose. Still further Arthur need not engage serially with Merlin, and could save all of his copies of $|\eta\rangle$ and run SWAP tests to make sure they are all the same, before doing his rotation based on a random $r$.

I'm not sure I understand the question. Is it about soundness, i.e. whether Merlin could cheat if he knew $i$?  Is this your question?  (And yes, of course he could, and I'm happy to give a 3-qubit example.)  --  One point which makes the question confusing (except that it is not phrased very clearly IMO) is that your suggest that $|\eta'\rangle$ is not the true ground state. This is not the point. The question is: Could Merlin use this to convince Artur that the ground state energy of the Hamiltonian is lower than it actually is?

@NorbertSchuch thanks - I've lightly edit it.  Yes, could Merlin send a fake $|\eta'\rangle$ state with the three qubits used in $H_i$ satisfying the test that Arthur will apply, and the other $n-k$ qubits in some other non-involved state?  Especially if Arthur only tests these three qubits only once, in a destructive manner.

Given $H=\sum H_i$, if Merlin knows which $H_i$ Artur will measure, he can just prepare a ground state of $H_i$ on the qubits on which $H_i$ acts (times anything on the rest).
Labeling the ground state energy of $H_i$ by $E_i$, the energy which Artur will then estimate (or for which he will accept) is $\sum E_i$. This energy is generally lower than the ground state energy $E$ of $H$. (The class of Hamiltonians where this is not the case, i.e., where $E=\sum E_i$, are called frustration free, and they are very special.)
The possibly simplest example is a 3-qubit system with a antiferromagnetic Heisenberg interaction between qubits 1-2 and 2-3. The ground state of each $H_i$ is a singlet state between the adjacent pair of qubits (and it is unique on those two qubits), but this is not compatible with a global state (due to monogamy of entanglement) -- the true ground state energy will thus have a higher energy.

Thanks! That matched my intuition... and was the reason why I had put that wording about Arthur catching a cheating Merlin into the previous post. But now I understand that Arthur has a lot of ways to avoid this particular problem - such as using Marriott-Watrous to reuse $|\eta\rangle$ for different $i$. I think when it was originally written up, they let Arthur's verification circuit choose $i$.

@Mark Note that for QMA, a 1/poly gap between acceptance probability for "yes" and "no" instances is sufficient, which you get by measuring a single H_i once. This can then be amplified by asking for several copies of the proof. The point of M-W is that it allows you to re-use the same proof, i.e. the size of the proof need not grow.

Thanks I meant “reuse the same $|\eta\rangle$ for different $i$”, which I think MW enables.

@Mark My point is that there is no "particular problem" to solve, by the very definition of QMA. The original protocol works just fine. Of course, other approaches also work, but for the ground state problem, phase estimation probably works better than M-W.
